# Очищать ли node_modules при каждом билде?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, devops, jenkins-pipeline

Настроил Jenkins pipeline для сборки Android приложения на React, но не уверен что делать с рабочей директорией.

А именно каждый билд делать с чистой директории, куда будет клонироваться репозиторий и скачиваться все необходимые зависимости: `node_modules, android-sdk`.

Или эти папки не очищать от билда к билду из соображений экономии трафика и времени сборки билда и это не приведёт к ошибкам вызванных оставшимися файлами от прошлых билдов?

Кто делать правильно? Заранее благоадрю.